# Is a IN subquery matching multiple columns possible in JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a SQL query I'm trying to convert to JPQL. The query is as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (myFirstColumn, mySecondColumn) IN (
    SELECT myFirstColumn, max(mySecondColumn)
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY myFirstColumn
)
```

My conversion attempt is straightforward :

```
select myObject
from MyObject as myObject
where (myObject.myFirstValue, myObject.mySecondValue) in (
    select subMyObject.myFirstValue, max(subMyOject.mySecondValue)
    from MyObject as subMyObject
    group by subMyObject.myFirstValue
)
```

MyObject is mapped to MyTable (using annotations).

If I understand the JPQL docs on the IN statement (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_in), and I'm really not sure I do, such a direct conversion isn't possible. Is there another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't find a way and had Java do the heavy lifting (ie. sorting one the second value and finding the biggest). It's not as pretty but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can change the query a little. You can use EXISTS instead of IN.

```
select myObject
from MyObject myObject
where exists
( 
   select subMyObject.myFirstValue, max(subMyOject.mySecondValue) 
   from MyObject subMyObject 
   where myObject.myFirstValue = subMyObject.myFirstValue 
   group by subMyObject.myFirstValue 
   having max(subMyOject.mySecondValue) = myObject.mySecondValue

)
```

Comment: I can indeed change the query and the SQL gets what I want, so I'm giving it a try. I hadn't thought about using the original request's values in the subquery as in `myObject.myFirstValue = subMyObject.myFirstValue` so it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried it and get an error, an nice and pretty **unexpected token [,]. Internal Exception: NoViableAltException**. I'll try again monday.

Comment: I think "as" token is redundant in query. I have just discarded them.